# Incorrect Node.js method call still compiles

Tags: node.js

So I have this method invocation

```
    let isAllowed = await checkAllowed[request];
```

This function was not awaiting properly, it would skip over execution and not invoke the function. The issue, which some of you eagle-eyed programmers will have spotted, is the square brackets.

My question is why does this even compile? CheckAllowed is a method name, it shouldn't have any properties on it, the object doesn't even exist (right?). The value of isAllowed was always "undefined"

Comment: If `checkAllowed` is a function, then all functions are objects and thus can have properties accessed with `fn[request]`.  If that property does not exist, then it's still not a coding error to reference it, it will just return `undefined`.

Comment: Oh, and `await undefined` just returns `undefined`.  It's not an error either.  But, obviously, no function is called when you do this so if that was your intent, then you would need `await checkAllowed(request)` or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In javascript function can have parameters.  You can see a function as an object.  This means that the following is valid

```
function checkAllowed(){
   return 1
}
checkAllowed.test = 0;

console.log(checkAllowed['test']) // should print 0
```

2. A property of an object can be a promise.  This means that the following is valid

```
const test = { field: new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(4),1000)) }
console.log(test.field) // Promise in a pending state
console.log(await test.field) // 4
```

Now we can look at the code in question.

```
let isAllowed = await checkAllowed[request];
```

First request is an object  It is used as an property accessor of a object so it will be use the string casting of the object (`[object Object]`).  This means that we know have the following equivalent code:

```
let isAllowed = await checkAllowed["[object Object]"];
```

Then it try to resolve the property on the `checkAllowed` function.  Here it does not exists so it is `undefined`.

```
let isAllowed = await undefined;
```

When we await a value this creates one or many promise(s) under the hood in the v8 engine but it is directly resolve.

```
let isAllowed = undefined;
```

This is kind of funky but it is valid javascript.

Comment: Thanks plp, accepting yours because of the super awesome examples!

Answer (score 1):

It's not calling a function. It's attempting to access a member of the object `checkAllowed` (without seeing the rest of the code, it's impossible to tell what kind of object `checkAllowed` is, as you can use object member accession like that for any type of object that contains members, like plain objects, functions, arrays, etc.) For example:

```
var checkAllowed = {
  foo: 'bar'
};

var XYZ = 'foo';

var ABC = checkAllowed[XYZ];

console.log(ABC); // => 'bar'
```

Comment: checkAllowed is a simple function, so I guess the missing piece here is that functions can be objects